# What is the preferred way of writing a loop in Java. Please have a look at the code below

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to add a node (`newNode`) to the end of a linked list and for that, I am trying to traverse to the end of the linked list.

My preferred way is by creating a reference to the `head` of the list and then parsing till we reach the last element. For this, I normally use the while loop.

```java
Node ptr = head;
while (ptr.next != null) {
   ptr = ptr.next;
}
ptr.next = newNode
```

I came across this for-loop which achieves the same

```java
Node p, q;
for (p = head; (q = p.next) != null; p = q);
p.next = newNode;
```

I am used to Python and the"pythonic" way of coding. Hence, I am wondering does Java have a more preferred way? and which amongst the two methods above would be preferred by an experienced Java developer?

Comment: There is no preferred way to do this, it depends on you as a programmer. Personally I think the while loop is more readable but thats my personal opinion. Side note, you dont have to traverse the list to add a new node at the end, you can keep a tail pointer which always point to the last node. And keep adding nodes to this node and make the new node as last node.

Comment: For this use case? The `while` loop looks more readable to me. But that's only one opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a subjective question, everyone (or most) would agree that the second option is **not** readable. I missed to notice the `;` at the end.

Make your code readable and easy to understand. Don't make it look smart.

Note: This doesn't mean that you should not use a *for* loop. Make the *for* loop equivalent to the *while* loop.

```
for (Node ptr = head; ptr.next != null;) {
    ptr = ptr.next;
}
```

Or, at least add an empty body `{}` to your *for* loop code.

```
for (p = head; (q = p.next) != null; p = q) {
}
```

I have seen static code analyzer rules set to up fail the compilation/build when loops have an empty body (explicit like above or when using a `;` at the end as in your question).